# I want to draw this two rectangles in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, zstack

I'm struggling on creating two vertical bars with lines and dash box. I would like to receive some suggestion on how to do this.

This is what I'm aiming to do:

[image]

Currently this is my code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoadManagementItemBarView: View {
    
    let isLeft: Bool
    let userWeight: Float
    @State var progress: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 490)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.positiveStappone)
                    .frame(width: 32, height: progress)
                
                VStack {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {

                        if isLeft {
                            Text("\(String(format: "%.0f", userWeight)) kg")
                        }
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 38, height: 1)
                        
                        if !isLeft {
                            Text("\(String(format: "%.0f", userWeight)) kg")
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(y: CGFloat(userWeight))
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .strokeBorder(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, dash: [10]))
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 188)
                        .offset(x: isLeft ? 24 : -23, y: -76)
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {

                        if isLeft {
                            Text(" 0 kg")
                        }
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 38, height: 1)
                        
                        if !isLeft {
                            Text(" 0 kg")
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(y: 11)
                }
                .offset(x: isLeft ? -24 : 23)
            }
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
    }
}

struct LoadManagementItemBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoadManagementItemBarView(
            isLeft: true,
            userWeight: 76,
            progress: 350
        )
    }
}
```

I tried to use ZStack to fit all of the UI components but I'm struggling with the offset of these component, example to modify it's y offset by just adding a max KG to the property created.
I want it to look like in the image below.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you split the background bar and the marker (the dashed box) into two separate View implementations, then apply the marker as an overlay. Something like:

```swift
private var backgroundBar: some View {
    // Implement the background bar here
}

private var marker: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .strokeBorder(
            style: StrokeStyle(
                lineWidth: 1,
                dash: [10]
            )
        )
        // Only the height needs to be specified
        .frame(height: myComputedHeight)

        // Only the y-offset needs to be specified
        .offset(y: myComputedOffset)
}

var body: some View {
    backgroundBar
        .overlay(marker, alignment: .top)
}
```

For iOS 15+ you probably want to use the new version of the `.overlay` modifier, the version I've used here has been deprecated.

For the bar scaling, two possible ways to approach would be:

- either, implement the scaling in another separate View and combine the views using an HStack
- or, include the scaling in the backgroundBar view and then add appropriate padding (left or right) to the marker.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 5, height: 50)
            Spacer()
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 5, height: 50)
        }
        Spacer()
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 2)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
    .border(Color.black, style: .dashed)
}
```

}

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add some context to your answer by explaining the code and how it solves the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).